# Notification of new membership sign up

Tags: drupal, civimember, contribution-page

I would like to be able to send a notification email to the office manager when a member joins through an online form.  The office manager should be notified for each new member.

How can I do this?

The membership form is set up as a contribution page.

I'm using CiviCRM 4.6.10 on Drupal 7.41.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use confirmation mails, it should be fairly simple:

1. go to "Contributions" --> "Manage Contribution Pages"
2. next to the contribution page in question, use the link "configure" and then "Thank-You and receipting"
3. tick the box "Email Receipt to Contributor" (if not ticked already) enter your office manager's email-address in the cc or bcc field

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  That's easier to set up than the profile method and seems to work reliably.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the advanced setting in a profile to email someone each time it it used. See "Notify when profile form is submitted?" in screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  This works for the individual membership page but doesn't seem to work for the organisation membership page.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you could also use the CiviRules extension (https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules) in combination with the extension for the email API (https://civicrm.org/extensions/e-mail-api). You could then set up a rule with membership added as a trigger, the membership type and/or status as conditions if required and the email send as action.